# How do I add a library project SherlockBar to the Android Studio?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I am importing a project from Eclipse. After import, I'm receiving many errors similar to:

```
 - java: ...\ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock-fest\src\main\java\org\fest\assertions\api\com\actionbarsherlock\view\ActionModeAssert.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method isNotNull()
location: class org.fest.assertions.api.com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionModeAssert
 - java: ...\ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock-fest\src\main\java\org\fest\assertions\api\com\actionbarsherlock\view\ActionModeAssert.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol: class AbstractAssert
 - java: ...\ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock-fest\src\main\java\org\fest\assertions\api\com\actionbarsherlock\view\ActionModeAssert.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method isNotNull()
location: class org.fest.assertions.api.com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionModeAssert
 - java: ...\ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock-fest\src\main\java\org\fest\assertions\api\com\actionbarsherlock\view\ActionModeAssert.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable actual
location: class org.fest.assertions.api.com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionModeAssert
java: ...\ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock-fest\src\main\java\org\fest\assertions\api\com\actionbarsherlock\view\ActionModeAssert.java:25: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method isNotNull()
location: class org.fest.assertions.api.com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionModeAssert
 - java: ...\ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock-fest\src\main\java\org\fest\assertions\api\com\actionbarsherlock\view\ActionModeAssert.java:26: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable actual
location: class org.fest.assertions.api.com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionModeAssert
 - java: ...\ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock-fest\src\main\java\org\fest\assertions\api\com\actionbarsherlock\view\ActionModeAssert.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertThat(android.view.View)
location: class org.fest.assertions.api.com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionModeAssert
```

Comment: Those are the unit tests of ActionBarSherlock. Import and build each module one at a time, and just build the unit tests last. In Android Studio, each related project is called a module, that is why I'm calling them modules.

Comment: Follow this steps http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-add-actionbarsherlock-library-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Two options :

1. You get the .jar and you add it into the `Libs` folder of your project.
2. You add Sherlock as an Android Porject into Android Studio and in you project `properties`, you add it as a library.